Slow boot Win10 (SSD)
Since a few weeks my computer boots slowly (3 to 4 minutes) and I can't figure out why so I did a boot trace where I really need some help with to interpret this data.
Click here for WPA screenshot
As far as I can see it has something to do with smss.exe in the Session Init phase, but then what? Thanks a lot in advance, since this already cost me so many hours of frustration.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Ramhound It probably isn't SQL. More likely Session Manager Subsystem SMSS.exe which is present in all Windows systems

Can you provide the output of: dir C:\Windows\System32\config. Thanks. I'm curious as to the size of SOFTWARE.

SOFTWARE is 721MB

Have you tried reparing the corrupted file with sfc/scannow ?

The size of the registry is the problem.  I need to have a think how best to "stat" it to work out what can be removed/which keys are the issue.  You could export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE to text and search that but it will be huge.  There must be better options....

Maybe try: https://www.sans.org/tools/registry-explorer/ you can load - Live System - Software. It at least gives number of subkeys. etc...

https://pastebin.com/raw/BimrsavM is a script that if you run from an elevated PS ISE window, it will print all the keys with more than 50 subkeys as a quick pass.

Since a few weeks we got at least 3 computers booting slowly, most probably since a BIOS update. Dell doesn't support going back to the old version and that's also not recommended since a lot of security issues are solved. They all show the same behaviour after logging in: a lot of Driver Installation Module processes running for almost half an hour after every boot. So I highly suspect this is a driver issue and I am sure that it can be found in the boot trace as long as you know where to look...

@superusereurope Do the laptops try to connect to a network drive which is no longer there?

The issue is the size of the registry.   We just need to stat it to see where the excessive data is and delete it.
